# Delphi TRegEx backreference broken?

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe4, backreference

I have a problem using `TRegEx.replace`:

```
var
  Value, Pattern, Replace: string;
begin
  Value   := 'my_replace_string(4)=my_replace_string(5)';
  Pattern := 'my_replace_string\((\d+)\)';
  Replace := 'new_value(\1)';
  Value   := TRegEx.Replace(Value, Pattern, Replace);
  ShowMessage(Value);
end;
```

The expected result would be `new_value(4)=new_value(5)`, while my code (compiled with Delphi XE4) gives `new_value(4)=new_value()1)`

With Notepad++, I get the expected result.

Using a named group makes it clear the `1` is the backreference treated literally:

```
Pattern := 'my_replace_string\((?<name>\d+)\)';
Replace := 'new_value(${name})';
// Result: 'new_value(4)=new_value(){name})'
```

The replacement is always that simple (could be zero or more times `my_replace_string`), so I could easily create a custom search-and-replace function, but I'd like to know what goes on here.

Is it my fault or is it a bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can reproduce the bug in Delphi XE4.  I get the correct behavior in Delphi XE5.

The bug was in `TPerlRegEx.ComputeReplacement`.  The code that I contributed to Embarcadero for inclusion with Delphi XE3 used `UTF8String`.  With Delphi XE4 Embarcadero eliminated `UTF8String` from the `RegularExpressionsCore` unit and replaced it with `TBytes`.  The developer that made this change seems to have missed a crucial difference between strings and dynamic arrays in Delphi.  Strings use a copy-on-write mechanism, while dynamic arrays do not.

So in my original code, `TPerlRegEx.ComputeReplacement` could do `S := FReplacement` and then modify the temporary variable `S` to substitute backreferences without affecting the `FReplacement` field because both were strings.  In the modified code, `S := FReplacement` makes `S` point to the same array as `FReplacement` and when backreferences in `S` are substituted, `FReplacement` is also modified.  Hence the first replacement is made correctly, while following replacements are wrong because `FReplacement` was crippled.

In Delphi XE5 this was fixed by replacing `S := FReplacement` with this to make a proper temporary copy:

```
SetLength(S, Length(FReplacement));
Move(FReplacement[0], S[0], Length(FReplacement));
```

When Delphi 2009 was released there was a lot of talk from Embarcadero that one shouldn't use string types to represent sequences of bytes.  It seems they are now making the opposite mistake of using TBytes to represent strings.

The solution to this whole mess, which I have previously recommended to Embarcadero, is to switch to the new pcre16 functions which use UTF16LE just like Delphi strings.  These functions did not exist when Delphi XE was released, but they do now and they should be used.

Comment: And those utf-16 functions are used by Jedi Code Lib. At least that does not waste time on utf-16 to utf-8 back to utf-16 roundtrips

Comment: Good to know that the JCL has already been updated to use pcre16.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear to be a bug. Here's my test program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  RegularExpressions;

var
  Value, Pattern, Replace: string;
begin
  Value   := 'my_replace_string(4)=my_replace_string(5)';
  Pattern := 'my_replace_string\((\d+)\)';
  Replace := 'new_value(\1)';
  Value   := TRegEx.Replace(Value, Pattern, Replace);
  Writeln(Value);
  Readln;
end.
```

On my XE3 the output is:

```
new_value(4)=new_value(5)
```

So it looks like  the bug was introduced in XE4. I suggest that you submit a QC report. Use my SSCCE above because it is standalone.

Comment: Thank you for the  confirmation

Comment: Fixed in XE5, so no QC report needed.